# Find number of solution tuples to a given inequality with combinatorics/stochastics involved?

Tags: combinatorics, stochastic-analysis

My problem has some practical background but on essence it circles around the following mathematical problem:
let $f(a,b,c)$ be a given function of a,b and c.
a,b and c can, totally random and depending on eahc other, be one of the values 1,2,3,...,10 or 11.
so every possible tuple from $(a,b,c)=(1,1,1)$ till $(11,11,11)$ is equally possible with probability
$(1/11)^3$.

given this, how likely is it that the value of $f(a,b,c)$ will be greater or equal than a given threshold?

Like for example
$f(a,b,c)=(1+a/100)*(1+b/100)*(1+c/100)$ and $f(a,b,c)>=1.37$
how likely will this inequality be fulfilled for $a,b,c$ being a number between 1 and 11 each?

I am well aware that one could draw a tree diagram and count all the paths that lead to an f vaulue bigger than the threshold.
and then just divide that number by $11^3$.

But I dont wanna do that cause in other isntances the possible numbers and also the number of variables might be bigger and "simply counting the paths by hand" might be impossible.

so I wonder how to do this via stochastics, there must be a smart way, right? :-)

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I just edited it

Comment: Is there a reason why you think stochastics will help? I suspect there is no answer other than checking every possible values of $(a, b, c)$, unless there are some nice properties of $f$.

Comment: Not really, its jsut that the selection proces of the a,b and c values is dependent on probability, so I would have assumed that stochastics and such has a way to find the wanted proability too, without checking each case :-)

Comment: There is no way to answer this question without some details about the function $f$. I suggest you specify your question more.

Comment: @MikeEarnest bernd said `Like for example` $f(a,b,c)=(1+a/100)(1+b/100)(1+c/100)$ and $f(a,b,c)\geq 1.37$ so maybe one can start with that.